# How to remove triplicate letters and leave duplicate in python?

Tags: python

Basically, I want to leave the double letters like 'ss' in guess and remove the 'iiiiiiiiiiiiiiii'

I'm cleaning data for text analytics.

```
s_input = "guess who just got shoes boiiiiiiiiiiiiii"

print(''.join(i for i, _ in itertools.groupby(s_input ))) #this also takes out the 'ss' in guess

>"guess who just got shoes boi"
```

The intent is to get the following
     "guess who just got shoes boi"

notice, 'guess' keeps the 'ss'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to get this done

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
>   occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the
>   pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged. repl can be a
>   string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it
>   are processed.

```
import re

s_input = "guess who just got shoes boiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
print(re.sub(r'(\w)\1{2,}',r'\1',s_input))
```

output:

```
guess who just got shoes boi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
print(''.join(i if len(g) > 2 else ''.join(g) 
              for i, g in itertools.groupby(s_input)
              for g in [list(g)]))
```

But that would be rather bad.

Answer (score 1):

For complicated generators, I like to write a generator function:

```
import itertools

def kill_long_dups(s):
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(s):
        group = list(group)
        if len(group) > 2:
            yield key
        else:
            yield from group


s_input = "guess who just got shoes boiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
print(''.join(kill_long_dups(s_input)))
```